# Cannot replace spaces using Bash variable expansion

Tags: bash, variables, replace

Why the tr command successfully replaces spaces with dashes in ls output:

`a=$(ls) ; b=$(echo $a | tr ' ' -) ; echo $b`

while I couldn't do the same by variable expansion:

`a=$(ls) ; b=${a// /-} ; echo $b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `echo $a` compresses all sequences of contiguous whitespace (including newlines) into a single space. This is [word splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) as described in the manual. Things will look differently if you quote your variables:

```
a=$(ls) ; b=$(echo "$a" | tr ' ' -) ; echo $b; echo "$b"
```

Unless you specifically want word splitting, always quote your variables.

Variable assignment is *not* subject to word splitting, so this part `b=${a// /-}` only replaces spaces in the filenames with hyphens but not the newlines that are part of the `ls` output.

Note that `ls` is intended to be read by human eyes. Don't parse the output of `ls`: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs